# XmlRpc client using Scala

Tags: scala, sbt, xml-rpc

I need to consume an xmlrpc service from Scala, and so far it looks like my only option is the Apache XML-RPC library.

I added this dependency to my `Build.scala`:

`"org.apache.xmlrpc" % "xmlrpc" % "3.1.3"`

and sbt reported no problem in downloading the library.   However, I don't know how to go about actually *accessing* the library.

`val xml = org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient("http://foo")` wouldn't compile

and

`import org.apache.xmlrpc._`

reported that *object xmlrpc was not a member of package org.apache*.

What would be the correct package to import?

(Or, is there a better library for XmlRpc from Scala?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
"org.apache.xmlrpc" % "xmlrpc-client" % "3.1.3"
```

and so :

```
  class XmlRpc(val serverURL: String) {

    import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient
    import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientConfigImpl
    import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransportFactory
    import java.net.URL
    val config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
    config.setServerURL(new URL(serverURL));
    config.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    val client = new XmlRpcClient();
    client.setTransportFactory(new XmlRpcSunHttpTransportFactory(client));
    client.setConfig(config);

    client.execute(...)
  }
```

Comment: Actually, I tried that as well.  The import statement worked, but I couldn't instantiate an XmlRpcClient object.  What would the fully qualified name be?

Comment: the class XmlRpcClient doesn't have a constructor with a String. See edit if it's correct for you

Comment: Thanks.  Had to add `import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransportFactory` and it compiled fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good module for this kind of tasks:
https://github.com/jvican/xmlrpc